# Clear All Breakpoints in VBA from VB script

Tags: vbscript, excel, vba

How can I Clear All Breakpoints in a VBA module from VB Script?

I need to make sure my VBA code always runs though, but sometimes I debug it and forget to remove all breakpoints.

Comment: Closing the workbook and reopening it is the most simplest way

Comment: Yes, that is rigth I just tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I close the Excel and open the workbook again the points are gone.

I have confirmed that in Office 2007 on Windows 7.

Thank you for the hint.

Comment: You are welcome  :) BTW it happens in all versions of Excel. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can clear all breakpoints by pressing CTRL SHIFT F9 - or by selecting the 'clear all breakpoints' from the debug menu

Answer (score 1):

stick it to initialization VBA module -- 
SendKeys "^+{F9}"